# Azure Function response null when returning to Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Can't seem to get my c# Azure Function to return data to my logic app correctly. Within the local Function testing I get the data correctly. When I call it from the Logic App I can see the content length returns as 0 when returned as a string. If I pass it as a json with number=foo, I can get the "number" key entry, but the value from foo is still blank.

[Local run within the Function gives the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnAtY.png)

[Data returned to the logic app shows Content length is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s56aU.png)

[output binding is default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVBoL.png)

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
{
    Content = new StringContent(foo, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have tested, it works fine in my site.

> Within the local Function testing I get the data correctly.

You mean you use azure portal to run the function and you could get the data.

I am not sure if you **make some logical judgments on `foo`**. If the `foo` value it null it would get the second picture you provided.

Here are my working steps and you could refer to:

1.Test with azure function on portal

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string foo="123456789";

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) 
    {
        Content = new StringContent(foo, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

2.Logic app design: use queue trigger
[image]

3.Add message in queue.
[image]